# Moving money into Fifth Third checking account through Access 360 card

Tags: united-states, banking, bank-account, money-transfer, debit-card

My account was one of those compromised a bit back, and as a result Fifth Third cancelled my card and gave me a prepaid Access 360 card. Due to some mail complications I never received my new card, and my account is currently over drafted due to sloppy budgeting from yours truly. My roommate is willing to give me some cash to bail me out, but I'm curious if there is any way to get that cash into my checking account to get it back to zero.

Comment: Do you have a savings account?

Comment: Yep, but the balance isn't enough to zero the acct. Edited to avoid embarrassment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to the ATM/debit card and with almost nothing in savings, you will probably have to visit a branch to make a cash deposit.

If it is too far to drive you might be able to turn the cash into a money order and mail it to the bank, but I would check with the bank to see if that would work. Of course mail will take a day or two.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Not to be annoying, but do you know if Fifth Third charges daily for overdrafts? Their copy is vague at best.

Comment: No idea. I don't have an account with them.